# Error:cannot implicity convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'OMS.Models.Product' An explicit Conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-5

In my ProductVM i have declared Domain Class(Product) as one of the property. However when i am querying the domainclass through a method i am unable to assign the resultant query to model .

```
ProductVm{
    public  Product Product { get; set;}

    public List<Image> Images { get; set; }

    public List<Specification> Specifications { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Edit Method in the controller

```
public ActionResult Edit(int?id) {
    ProductVM Vm = new ProductVM();

    Vm.Product = GetProductDetails(id);

    Vm.Images = GetImages(id);

    Vm.Specifications = GetSpecifications(id);
    return View(Vm);

}

public Product GetProductDetails(int? id) {

    var prod_details = from p in db.Products
                           where p.ProductID == 5002
                           select p;
                           return prod_details; //// Error: cannot implicity  convert type 

 }
```

Throw this error:

> 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'OMS.Models.Product'An explicit Conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning an IQueryable of Products, not a single Product. Try this out:

```
public Product GetProductDetails(int? id) 
{
    var prod_details = from p in db.Products
                       where p.ProductID == id // i think you meant id not 5002
                       select p;
    return prod_details.FirstOrDefault(); 
}
```